# SQLiteException: table X has no column named Y

Tags: java, android, sql

I am trying to use the SQLDatabase as a of objects of class Todo(int id, String name, String date, String note). After creating helper by following piece of code:

```
package com.example.todoistodo;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class TodoSQLiteHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public TodoSQLiteHelper(Context context) {
        // Databse: todos_db, Version: 1
        super(context, "todos_db", null, 1);
    }

    // todos
    //      _id     - key
    //      todo    - todo text
    //      date    - todo date
    //      note    - todo note

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        // Execute create table SQL
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE todos (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT , todo TEXT NOT NULL , date TEXT NOT NULL , note TEXT NOT NULL);");
    }


    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVer, int newVer) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS todos");
        onCreate(db);
    }

}
```

..and creating object to query database:

```
package com.example.todoistodo;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;

public class TodoDAO {

    private SQLiteDatabase db;
    private TodoSQLiteHelper dbHelper;

    public TodoDAO(Context context) {
        dbHelper = new TodoSQLiteHelper(context);
        db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    }

    public void close() {
        db.close();
    }

    public void createTodo(String todoName, String todoDate, String todoNote) {
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put("todo", todoName);
        contentValues.put("date", todoDate);
        contentValues.put("note", todoNote);
        db.insert("todos", null, contentValues); //lane 30
    }

    public void deleteTodo(int todoId) {
        db.delete("todos", "_id = " + todoId, null);
    }

    //get every single Todo
    public List<Todo> getTodos() {
        List<Todo> todoList = new ArrayList<Todo>();

        String[] tableColumns = new String[] {"_id","todo","date","note"};

        Cursor cursor = db.query("todos", null, null, null, null, null, null); // null as second param instead of tableColumns
        cursor.moveToFirst();

        while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
            Todo todo = new Todo();

            todo.setId(cursor.getInt(0));
            todo.setName(cursor.getString(1));
            todo.setDate(cursor.getString(2));
            todo.setNote(cursor.getString(3));

            todoList.add(todo);

            cursor.moveToNext();
        }

        return todoList;
    }

}
```

I get an SQLiteException in db.insert("todos", null, contentValues); of createTodo method.
What's wrong with my code?
Here is the related log:

```
08-06 22:43:34.902: I/SqliteDatabaseCpp(23902): sqlite returned: error code = 1, msg = table todos has no column named date, db=/data/data/com.example.todoistodo/databases/todos_db
08-06 22:43:34.922: E/SQLiteDatabase(23902): Error inserting date=Tomorrow  note= todo=Sleep out
08-06 22:43:34.922: E/SQLiteDatabase(23902): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: table todos has no column named date: , while compiling: INSERT INTO todos(date,note,todo) VALUES (?,?,?)
08-06 22:43:34.922: E/SQLiteDatabase(23902):    at com.example.todoistodo.TodoDAO.createTodo(TodoDAO.java:30)
```

Thank you!

Comment: did you recently updated the table structure??

Comment: If you have added date field after the first run, you will need to update the DB version to recreate the database or delete application files.

Comment: @Akhil Jain No, I'm actually didn't. How should I update it?

Comment: you need to drop the table, various ways are to do that-> manually write the query to drop the table, clear the app cache, the reason for updating is at ,once table is created, it is not recreated, even if you add new column in table , if you have done so, DROP THE TABLE.

next time table will be recreated/created, with new columns

Comment: You can force database update by change version here: super(context, "todos_db", null, 1); 2 instead of 1.

Comment: Thank you guys, both advices are helpfull!

Answer (score 0):

This line has something wrong:

```
db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE todos (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT , todo TEXT NOT NULL , date TEXT NOT NULL , note TEXT NOT NULL);");
```

It should be without the ';'

```
db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE todos (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT , todo TEXT NOT NULL , date TEXT NOT NULL , note TEXT NOT NULL)");
```

Comment: I'm sure it doesn't change anything, `;` is just a delimiter in SQL to say "hey, here starts another query!"